# Laravel 5.2 TokenGuard implementation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How to use token guard to create API? I tried it to implement it and I am getting error

> call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
>   class 'Illuminate\Auth\TokenGuard' does not have a method 'attempt'

Comment: Maybe you would be so kind to post a piece of code you wrote?

Comment: I want to implement the api token guard provided in laravel 5.2.I want the process to implement  authentication by Api guard.The core document do not explain it much

Comment: As I said, show your code

Comment: I have found a very detailed documentation help here. https://gistlog.co/JacobBennett/090369fbab0b31130b51 It tells you how to setup Token Based auth with Laravel. Maybe this might be of help? [edit] This link give your information of how to do a token based authentication using Laravel 5.2
I would like to put the response here but the link here is very detailed and very long

Answer (score 4):

After dig into the source code of laravel, I found that the token guard is useless for now. All auth are passed to auth middleware, from there, you can see that it called `Auth::guard($name)->guest()` to check whether the user is logged in. The `\Auth::guard` will get the proper guard that you specified in route. Let's say here is the TokenGuard. In \Illuminate\Auth\TokenGuard, check the `user` function to see how `TokenGuard` get a user. First, it will get the input parameter named `api_token`. Then it will let the provider which may be eloquent as the default configuration to search a value in the database. If any value is found, a new user instance is created. If there is not a input value named `api_token`, then some other choices will be tried:

1. bearerToken, which the Authorization HTTP header value that starts with: bearer.
2. password, which passed through HTTP header: PHP_AUTH_PW.

which key to match in the model is specified by the protected property `storageKey`.

So the token guard is used to implemented third-party API access token, not a temporary access token that is stored in the session.

Comment: You could generate the token at login and delete it at logout, however that would mean you could only be logged in on one device at a time, and also its just like reimplementing the session in a much more primitive way. You might be better just using the session key via a param.

Comment: well, basic auth in larvael is based on session and in api, session is not implemented so we need token to do it